# How do I refresh a form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've built a form which can add/delete records to an SQL database. When I add a record, I want the form to reload and the listbox with all the records to now include the newly added record.

I googled this and saw that a new thread was recommended to refresh the form, but the instructions weren't clear enough for a newbie like me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is a desktop app using c# and not asp.

Some of the controls are populated by a wizard that I ran and for others I coded the datasource myself.

```
namespace LomWindows
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(global::LomWindows.Properties.Settings.Default.esConnectionString);
            tConnStr.Text = global::LomWindows.Properties.Settings.Default.esConnectionString;

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlComm = "INSERT INTO ES_TOOL ....";

            try
            {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception exce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exce.ToString());
            }

            try
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }

            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show("Tool Added");
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET or Desktop application?

Comment: Can you show how you add records to listbox and database. Do you use data binding? Or you do it yourself? Code, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might rebind the control again after add/edit/delete this will reload the controls with the updated data.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to code a reload of a form? In my more complicated forms that are a number of controls that I've linked to the database (my code- not a wizard). Surely there must be a simple command to do this along the lines of this.repaint()?

Comment: My code is way too big for posting here, but I'll post the relevant bits (I hope) above, as an edit.

Comment: I tried this:lstToolOpen.DataSource = null;
            lstToolOpen.DataSource = this.eSTOOLBindingSource;      But it didn't work

Comment: I think u don't have to assign null for the datasource but for some cases you might clear the rows first before the next bind

Answer (score 1):

**WinForms**

There is a great article over at MSDN covering the following: [Give Your .NET-based Application a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx).

When you want to Re-draw your window you can call the method [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). However when you Re-bind a control; setting a new datasource, it will update the content in it.

Here are some great videos to watch for WinForms: ["How Do I  Videos" from WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx).

**WPF**

Here is a matching article to the one in WinForms covering: [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).

Herer are some great videos to watch for WPF: ["How Do I Videos"](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx), aslo from WindowsClient.net.

**ASP.NET**

If you want to create more responsive webbapps you might want to consider having a look at jQuery and Ajax. You can then request a new part of your web-site and replace the old one.

However if you are just doing a postback and you want to add items to your listbox, you can just call `DataBind` on the `ListBox` and it should re-bind the items in the data-source.

Comment: I tried adding this.invalidate() to the end of the record adding function (run by clicking on a button), private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). It didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Dave, you need to re-fetch the ListBox from your database and re-bind it using `.DataSource`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Could you show me some code?

Comment: @Dave, What you need to do is load all records from the database into your Data Source.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying question isn't really about Winforms repaints, rather it's how to freshen the datasource to which the Winform controls are bound, or from which the controls are being manually populated in unbound mode, after the database has been changed by your client application.

Unless you create the data model, your datasource object has no way of knowing that the data have been changed when a DML statement is executed by a command somewhere. It all has to be "tied together". ADO.NET uses a 'disconnected recordset' model.  The ADO.NET datalayer objects will raise events related to data i/o and data errors, and you must must attach listeners/eventhandlers to them; these eventhandlers must, in turn, invoke your presentation-layer code.

At present you're just scratching the surface with the command object. Best thing to do would be to read one of the books that show you how to wire up eventhandlers to the ADO.NET event model.

EDIT: Here's a link to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's ASP.NET you can refresh the form by redirecting it to itself by using the following code:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawRul);
```

If it's a Windows Application, you need to rebind the listbox control by setting its DataSource property again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already calling `Invalidate` on the ListBox, you might want to add a debug statement to the `Paint` method to make sure it's really repainting. If it is, then you should look into where `Paint` gets the state needed to draw the items. Do you query the database inside `Paint`? (I hope not.) Or is the form keeping its state in memory somewhere? In that case, you should make sure that you're keeping the in-memory state consistent with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of the performance impact of re-loading all the rows whenever **one** row is added/deleted/updated? IMHO, reloading the entire data will just annoy the users and also increase the bandwidth usage. Instead, create POCO objects for each line of data. Whenever there is a (successful) CRUD operation (which you perform on the `BackgroundWorker` component), just add it to the `DataSource` and call `DataBind`.

For more information on how to use `BackgroundWorker`, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx).

Comment: It's an interesting point. At the moment this is a pretty small scale project and my priority is easy coding. But I'll definitely read up on POCO when I get a chance.

Comment: @Dave Then why do you need a separate thread? Just perform the CRUD on the main thread itself, refresh the `DataSource` (of only that particular control) and `DataBind`.

Answer (score 0):

Write Select query in Form_Load and call after where ever you need to refresh your form like,

```
form_load(Object sender,Event_args e)
  {

   select Query to display on Loading form
  }
add_click(Object sender,Event_args e)
 {
 form_load(sender,e);
 }
```